# Listview to display info supplied by the user in a fragment that is also with in tabs

Tags: java, android, listview, tabs, fragment

Here is my situation. I have three tabs, now I painstakingly found out that these tabs have to be fragments and that is still something that am wrapping my head around I've gotten a good handle on them because the first fragment has a button that starts a new fragment, which we will call deduction fragment. Now here is my goal. I need the information that I gathered from the deduction fragment, which is being stored in a Shared Preferences file(which is also something I am new to, good handle on it but still a bit shaky) to be displayed in the list view that is on the tabbed fragment. One more thing that I think I should mention is that there is a textview on the tabbed fragment that I need to calculate the net income of the user.

Here is my code for the first tab activity that am stuck on:
As you can see by all of the imports I have tried alot of stuff that still hurts my head.

```
package com.eulondk3.dellaj;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class IncomeFragment extends ListFragment implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    private Fragment thisFragment;
    TextView tvChange;
    Button toDeductions;
    ListView listview1;
    List<String> deductionName = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList <String> list = new ArrayList <String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    public static final String DEDUCTIONS_PREFS_FILE = "deductionslist";
    SharedPreferences prefses = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(DEDUCTIONS_PREFS_FILE, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor edittor = prefses.edit();


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ViewGroup gifraglayout = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.gross_income_fragment, null);
        return gifraglayout;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab IncomeTab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab IncomeTab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        thisFragment = new IncomeFragment();
        ft.add(android.R.id.content, thisFragment);
        ft.attach(thisFragment);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab IncomeTab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ft.remove(thisFragment);

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        tvChange = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.tvgrossIncomeInfo);
        tvChange.setText("Your Goss Income is : $" + Userdata.user_income + ", would you like to add a deduction?");

        toDeductions = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.addDeduc);
        toDeductions.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent calltoDeductions = new Intent("com.eulondk3.dellaj.DEDUCT");
                startActivity(calltoDeductions);
            }
        });

        listview1 = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    }}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! In order to help the community better answer your question, it's helpful if you can reduce it to a minimal form. If you're able to shorten this question and/or eliminate the long code listings, you might have better luck getting a helpful answer.

Comment: Nobody is going to waste their some reading through all of this... please refer to http://sscce.org/ in an effort to create an SSCCE. This will allow others to easily recognize the problem and thus providing you concrete specific feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Try saving the data you got in JSON file (you can use GSON library for java) and then try putting the JSON data in a String and put it inside a SharedPreference. And if whenever you want to use that data, retrive the JSON, parse it (GSON library for java) and process the data for results.